# help core data tableview not reloading

Tags: uitableview, core-data

i am using core data...my table view does not reload say if i add a new row to the table. until i terminate the app and re open it...im calling reloadData in my root controller viewwillappear method... any help would be appreciated

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you are using a `NSFetchedResultsController`?  If you are not then you need to be with a `UITableView`.  Once you do, make sure you have your `UITableViewDatasource` configured as the delegate to the `NSFetchedResultsController`.  Once you do that, you will not need to call `-reloadData` at all because the `NSFetchedResultsController` will monitor changes in the `NSManagedObjectContext` and update the `UITableViewDatasource` as needed via the delegate methods.